# Please criticize my proof about the torus theorem.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I'm tackling an exercise from Hatcher's "Notes on Basic 3-manifold Topology"

> Use the method of proof of Alexander's theorem to show that every torus $T\subset S^3$ bounds a solid torus $S^1\times D^2\subset S^3$ on one side or the other.

Here is my proof.
I'm not that accustomed to 3-manifold yet.
So, please let me know what is wrong here, and how to improve the proof by adding, possibly, detailed explanations.
Thanks!

[An (incomplete) proof without the method of the proof of Alexander's theorem] Denote a two-ball(disk) by $B^2$, instead of $D^2$. Similarly, denote a three-ball by $B^3$.

Consider a meridian $C$ of $T$.
The circle $C$ is a compressing disk for $T$.
Surgering $T$ along $C$ produces a capped cylinder $(B^2\times\{0\})\cup(S^1\times I)\cup(B^2\times\{1\})$.
Note that we can recover $T$ from the cylinder by removing the caps and identifying $x\times 0$ with $x\times 1$ for each $x\in S^1$.
The capped cylinder, which is homeomorphic to $S^2$, bounds a $B^3$ by the Alexander's theorem, and $B^3$ is homeomorphic to $B^2\times I$.
Thus the capped cylinder bounds $B^2\times I$.
Recovering $B^2\times I$ by identifying $x\times 0$ with $x\times 1$ for each $x\in B^2$, we get a solid torus $B^2\times S^1$.
Since the capped cylinder bounds $B^2\times I$, the torus $T$ bounds the solid torus $B^2\times S^1$.
If $\partial B^2$ serves as a meridian $C$ of $T$, the recovered solid torus will be the standard solid torus(the solid torus $B^2\times S^1$ with $\partial B^2=C$).
If $\partial B^2$ serves as a longitude of $T$, the recovered solid torus will be the complement of the standard solid torus(the solid torus $B^2\times S^1$ with $S^1=C$).